# css tooltip goes off screen

Tags: css, tooltip, screen

I'm using a pure CSS tooltip on this page: http://theroadmap.co/generation/

On small screen, hovering over some longer tooltips on right column causes tooltip to go off screen. Is there any way to get it to wrap when it reaches right end of screen?

Here is code for the tooltip:

```
/* TOOLTIP TIME */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip:hover:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: .5em;
    content: attr(href);
    min-width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: -32px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: CSS media queries to reduce width of tooltip?

Comment: thanks! problem is, some tooltips exceed even 1920 width - the issue here is that I don't know how to wrap text in tooltip, even non-automatically...

Comment: A tooltip that large really shouldn't be used like that.

Comment: I agree that it's been problematic so far - would you have a better suggestion? This site has done it well: [http://www.noexcuselist.com/]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
   if((mousey+100)>$(window).height())
   {

    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey-100 ,left: mousex })

   }
   else if((mousex+200)>$(window).width())
   {
      $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey ,left: mousex-200})

   }
   else
    {
   $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem when i tried to display a file name. seems like the name was too long and there weren't any spaces in it, so i used

```
word-break: break-all;
```

in my .tooltip class. 
this is my funtion for tooltip:

```
  $('.file_attachments').hover(function () {
                                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"></div>';
                                // Hover over code
                                var title = $.trim($(this).attr('title'));

                                if (title.length > 0) {
                                    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                                    $('body').append(tooltip);
                                    $('.tooltip').html(title);
                                    $('.tooltip').fadeIn('slow');
                                } else {
                                    $('body').append(tooltip);
                                }

                            }, function () {
                                // Hover out code
                                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                                $('.tooltip').remove();
                            }).mousemove(function (e) {
                                var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                                var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                                $('.tooltip').css({top: mousey, left: mousex})
                            });
```