# How to nudge a positioned tip associated with an image to the right if it would extend off the left-hand side?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem trying to keep some help text associated with a "?" image positioned appropriately horizontally. Although it works as I would like most of the time, when the "?" moves too close to the left of the screen (either because the "?" is close to the left in the first place, or a width reduction wraps it there), the help gets chopped off

I like it to appear in a box 15rem wide, as high as it needs to be, positioned above and extending to the left of the "?", and to be visible on either a hover or click. That works fine.

What I can't figure out is **how to move the help to the right by just as much as is necessary to avoid it extending off the left-hand side of the screen whenever that is necessary**.

I have added another class (not shown) to those tips that I know are near the left, that extends them right instead of left. However it's not a good solution, relying on me finding them, and not coping with window resizing very well.

What I have so far is:

HTML And CSS:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    height: 20px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    width: 15rem;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext, .tooltip:active .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name=xx size="40" placeholder="xxxxxx">
    <span class="tooltip">
        <img src="static/help.png" alt="help">
        <span class="tooltiptext">Some help text for this.</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm guessing the key is dynamically determining the position of tooltiptext and adjusting left/right accordingly but I'm at a loss to know how to do that. I'm limited to CSS & JS (i.e. not JQuery).

Any help gratefully accepted.
Thanks, Chris

Comment: Here are similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488926/keep-tooltip-inside-of-parent-container -- and -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337452/css-tooltip-goes-off-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is not quite well solution, but it gives you some useful thoughts.

```
let tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');

[].forEach.call(tooltips, (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', showTooltip, this);
});

function setDefaultPosition(element) {
    element.style.top = 'auto';
    element.style.right = 'auto';
    element.style.bottom = 'auto';
    element.style.left = 'auto';
}

function showTooltip(event) {
    let tooltip = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.tooltiptext')
    setDefaultPosition(tooltip);
    let {top:bodyTop, right:bodyRight, bottom:bodyBottom, left:bodyLeft} = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    let {top:tooltipTop, right:tooltipRight, bottom:tooltipBottom, left:tooltipLeft} = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (bodyTop < tooltipTop) {
        tooltip.style.top = '100%';
    }
    if (bodyBottom < tooltipBottom){
        tooltip.style.bottom = '100%';
    }
    if (bodyRight < tooltipRight) {
        tooltip.style.right = '100%';
    } 
    if (bodyLeft > tooltipLeft){
        tooltip.style.left = '100%';
    }
};
```

[Example here](http://js.do/code/163726)

Comment: That gave me all the pointers I needed, thank you! Minor typo - "botton" in setDefaultPosition(). I simply took out the top/bottom parts of the code and set the vertical positioning statically in the css (I wanted the tip above rather than below where I know there is plenty of room).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more than on CSS solution. It could be done with `flexbox`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJpQWE

```
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  width: 100%; /* adjust the with to your needs */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.some-input {
  width: 100%;
}

.tooltip > img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  padding: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext, .tooltip:active .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```